# Quitting my job - Can I stay In Germany if my residence card is valid?

Tags: working-visas, germany

I am deputed in Germany from an Indian Employer with work permit which is valid till January 2019. But now my employer wants me to come back to India before January 2019. My query is:

"Can I stay back in Germany till January 2019 on the same visa if I quit my job and look for another one if I can take care of my living expenditure.?"

Comment: What kind of visa do you have? Is there something like "valid only for work in company X"?

Comment: Depends on what the visa says. You should probably ask a city official or at the "Auswärtiges Amt" which is the federal agency responsible for handling this.